# MongoDB PHP Driver is not working

Tags: php, macos, apache, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am having Mac OSX 10+, I am using Xampp im my system. I need to install PHP Mongodb driver to connect it to mongodb for my application but It's not working, I have tried following steps:

1. Installed Mongodb driver using 
       `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongo`
2. Added `extension="mongo.so" to php.ini /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc`

But after that It's not letting Apache Server to start; if I remove `extension="mongo.so"` from `php.ini` then it's able to start again

Method 2:

1. Installed Mongodb driver using 
       `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongodb`
2. Added `extension="mongodb.so"` to `php.ini /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc`

But after that It's not letting Apache Server to start; if I remove `extension="mongodb.so"` from `php.ini` then it's able to start again

I am able to see the `mongo.so` and `mongodb.so` file at location `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226`

Error I am getting in log file of Xampp is given below:

```
[Tue Apr 05 15:48:23.002151 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 59298] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Apr 05 15:48:23.002443 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 59298] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Apr 05 15:48:23.002603 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 59298] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/suexec)
[Tue Apr 05 15:48:24.002160 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 59299] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Apr 05 15:48:24.002291 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 59299] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Apr 05 15:48:24.002510 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 59299] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Apr 05 15:48:24.002550 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 59299] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
```

Comment: My PHP Version is 5.6.19

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165264/mongodb-php-driver-causing-apache-on-xampp-os-x-to-fail?rq=1 
this link is having same issue but no result

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution from a Youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YStM8_HWxRI

It's very useful and give you step by step explanation for the same.

The problem I was getting because I was updating wrong php.ini file, I was updating /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini instead of /Applications/XAMPP/etc/php.ini